# Sending ASP.NET variable/account information to Android device

Tags: android, asp.net

I'm using an Android device to display an ASP.NET MVC web application and I was wondering if it's possible to send account information to the android device?

My main goal is to use the users account log-in details to set up a specific save path on the android. If I was able to send the users log-in username to the android device this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting one of the links which deals with this topic extensively (a well written article) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap. [NOTE: This solution utilizes the KSOAP library jar for android platform. ]

Basically you would want to have one of the web service methods return the logged-in user, this method can be invoked by Android's native java class.